# Why is it best to store a telephone number as a string vs. integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

As the question states, why is it considered best practice to store telephone numbers as strings rather than integers in the telephone_number column?

Not sure I understand the rationale for this. Please help clear this up!

Thanks!

Comment: This was a fun Q/A!  I love the confusion caused by not specifying that "phone numbers are strings of digit characters we represent with integers".  I'm guessing the characters used "under the covers" are represented by integers because they map to integers ([bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)).  I'm seeing similar confusion popping up in a lot of things due to imprecise natural language.  So phone numbers are integers and they're not, depending on the context.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Telephone numbers are strings of digit characters, they are not integers.

Consider for example:

- Expressing a telephone number in a different base would render it meaningless
- Adding or multiplying two telephone numbers together, or any math operation on a phone number, is meaningless. The result is not another telephone number (except by conicidence)
- Telephone numbers are intended to be entered "as-is" into a connected device.
- Telephone numbers may have leading zeroes.
- Manipulations of telephone numbers, such as adding an area code, are String operations.

Storing the string version of the telephone number makes this clear and unambiguous.

---

History: On old pulse-encoded dial systems, the code for each digit in a telephone number was sent as the same number of pulses as the digit (or 10 pulses for "0"). That may be why we still use digits to represent the parts of a phone number. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_dialing

Comment: For user's phone numbers, would you always have a single field? if so, would that also be the case for international numbers?

Comment: @stevec: That's partly up to you and a different question I think. For most use cases, I would personally use a single field and a library that could parse the numbers to separate out dial codes etc if it was important, because I would not want to put that requirement on users of a system to put the correct parts into the right boxes in a multi-field version. However, in some use cases it might be convenient to separate into logical components on input or when storing the number.

Answer (score 11):

What Neil Slater said is correct.  I would add that there are lots of edge cases where you can't express a telephone number as a number value consistently.

For example, consider these numbers:

```
011-123-555-1212
+11-123-555-1212
+1 (112) 355-5121 x2
```

These are all potentially valid phone numbers, but they mean very different things. Yet, in integer form, they are all `111235551212`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are going to store the number for display from input, then you must use a string.

However, while it is true that no mathematical operations can be performed on a number that have meaning. Using a number in hashsets and for indexing is quicker than using a string. So provided you can guarantee or homogenise your set of numbers, so they are all consistent, then you may see better performance operating on a number.

For example, in the Telco world, rating calls for a given customer includes a lot of searching on their CLI and in this situation it is faster and cheaper to search by integer. Generally though strings will be fine performance wise, it is only where performance matters and you have multiple searches to perform for a huge range of numbers - i.e. Rating 250 million calls across 2 million lines and 2000 tariffs. In memory rating also gets expensive, so being able to use a 64bit int or uint is cheaper when dealing with these volumes.

Comment: Upvoted because I *have* written one and working with phone numbers as integers in the database is far faster. The downside of course is weird looking arithmetic when you need the NXX or 1000 block ID.

Comment: Upvoted since I've implemented multiple projects at large Telcos and fully agree with your experience.

Answer (score 7):

Consider these phone numbers for example

`099-1234-56789` or `+91-8907-687665`.

In this case,if the `phone_number` attribute is of type `integer`,then it can't accept these values.It should be a `string` to hold these type of values.So `string` is always preferred than `integer`

Answer (score 4):

There is several reasons for this :

- Phone numbers often start with a "0" : an integer will remove all leading "0"s
- Phone number can have special char : `+`, `(`, `-`, etc. (for exemple : +33 (0)6 12 23 34)
- You cannot perform operations on phones : adding phones, for instance, would be meaningless
- Phone number may be internationalised, i.e. different format for different people, thus not possible with integers

There might be other reasons, but I guess that's already a fair amount of those :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it is important to think out of the box

Taking most upvoted post and demonstrating step by step why it **does** make sense to store as an integer:

- Expressing a telephone number in a different base would render it meaningless
  -> we don't care that's not the purpose.
- Adding or multiplying two telephone numbers together, or any math operation on a phone number, is meaningless. The result is not another telephone number (except by conicidence)
  -> Ok we understood your point the phone number is not to make mathematics.
- Telephone numbers are intended to be entered "as-is" into a connected device.
  -> ok, ever heard about parsing inputs?
- Telephone numbers may have leading zeroes.
  -> only one leading 0 is possible.
- Manipulations of telephone numbers, such as adding an area code, are String operations.
  -> here we are talking about DB storage.

#### TLDR

We don't care that it is indeed a string. It costs space to the DB.

A big integer is 8 bytes, versus 10 or more bytes for a string (especially if you keep parenthesis etc) inside the DB.

If you have millions of users you save a lot of space by: 1/ stripping any non-digit from user input and 2/ storing the phone number as an integer.

When you retrieve it, depending on the length you can then add a `+` or a leading 0.